# Type casting issue: Returning as integer instead of float/type

Tags: c++, casting, user-defined-functions, typecasting-operator

I am trying to return average to the main which has computed the average number of elements per array. Sum is an integer, numTweets is an integer. I try type casting these to double or float types, but it still return an integer value. The true average is 167.5, but it is returning 168. I have attached photos of the call to the function in main and the function header/definition.

**Function prototype:**

```
double histogram (int length [], int numTweets);
```

**Call to function:**

```
average = histogram (length, numTweets);
printf ("Average length of all tweets = %.f\n", average);
```

**Function header/definition:**

```
double histogram (int length[], int numTweets) {
    int i, j;
    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < numTweets; i++) {
        printf("Tweet %d:", i + 1);
        for (j = i; j < length[i]; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        sum = sum + length[i];
        printf("\n");
    }
    average = (float)sum / (float)numTweets;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: What is `average` in the call to `histogram`?

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you start the inner loop at `j == i`? The remaining code shown here looks correct.

Comment: average is declared in main as a double data type

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: sorry I should have added, after the call to function in main. There is a                      
printf statement. I have updated it.

Comment: I suggest that you add `std::cout << sum << " " << numTweets << "\n";`  just before `return average;` and include the output from that line in the question. Also, add `std::cout << histogram (length, numTweets); << "\n";` and the output that gives. It should clear any confusion regarding types and values.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since I used `printf`, but `%.f` seems to treat is as `%.0f` If you specify a number after the `.`, or don't specify anything and just use `%f`, then this should fix your issue. The function is returning the correct value.

https://godbolt.org/z/sG_ns2

From : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf (bold is me)

> (optional) . followed by integer number or *, or neither that specifies precision of the conversion. In the case when * is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type int. If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. **If neither a number nor * is used, the precision is taken as zero**. See the table below for exact effects of precision.

Comment: So this is as assignment, where the main is given by the instructor and I'm to complete the function body's. I'm not supposed to change anything in the main, so I cannot change the printf statement. Since you believe the printf statement is the issue, would you suggest I contact the instructor?

Comment: I would recommend asking the instructor about it, yes. It may be that s/he did that on purpose, or was a simple typo. Could also be that their compiler treats it differently, although I've tried with 3 compilers and they all work the same, so likely a typo.

Comment: Okay thanks I will ask. They want average to be returned as a double with 2 decimal places but this seems unlikely to happen given the print statement as you pointed out.

Comment: I've added a reference. `printf` should default to `0` precision if nothing follows the `.`